# Django : Operational Error while using ManytoMany Field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, many-to-many

This seems to be a silly problem but just dosn't go away.
My goal is make a simple Post,Sharing,Comments,likes etc application.
Most of the functionalities seem to work fine with posting and commenting on post.
So I have a model called UserPost and another model called Comments. Comment model field has a comment_liked_by field which is ManytoMany relation to Django User Model and it is basically to store the users who have liked the particular comment.This is my models.py:-

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
post_created    =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
post_last_edit  =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
post_text_body  =  models.TextField(verbose_name='Share Yourself')
post_user_handle = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name='Username',default=User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post_share       = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Public')
#post_image       = models.ImageField(blank=True,verbose_name='Add a Photo')
def __str__(self):
    return (self.post_user_handle.first_name+" "+self.post_user_handle.last_name)


def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('feedviews')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Latest Post"
    verbose_name_plural = "Latest Posts"
    ordering = ["-post_created"]

class Comments(models.Model):
comment_body  = models.TextField(verbose_name="Add Comment")
comment_likes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
comment_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
comment_user_handle = models.OneToOneField(User,default=User,related_name='Commented_by')
comment_post  = models.ForeignKey(UserPost,verbose_name='Post ID')
comment_liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='Like_List')

def __str__(self):
    return (self.comment_user_handle.first_name+" "+self.comment_user_handle.last_name+"\n"+self.comment_body+"\n")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Latest Comment"
    verbose_name_plural = "Latest Comments"
    ordering = ["-comment_created"]
```

In views.py I call a function that gets the arguments of post_id , comment_id and username to identify the comment object that has to be updated when a user likes the comment.Here is my views.py :-

```
def LikeComment(request,username,post_id,comment_id):
   user = User.objects.get(username=username)
   post = UserPost.objects.get(post_user_handle=user,id=post_id)
   comment = post.comments_set.get(id = comment_id)
   comment.comment_liked_by.add(request.user)
   comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

The problem is everytime I run the server and a user clicks like ,adding request.user to the comment_liked_by set, I get an Operational Error with no such table called comment_liked_by. I have ran makemigration and migrate without issue.Where am I going wrong?Is the onetoone relation with User model and Many to Many relation fields clashing? I have tried to implement this with a foreign Key but that seems more complicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try that in your django shell, see if it's the same thing. Also try your db shell and manually check if the field is there and name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, but I identified something strange.
In the model Comments, the field comment_user_handle has a default value that is not correct. I suggest to remove it.

It's possible that because of that Django is not updating the database.

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment_body  = models.TextField(verbose_name="Add Comment")
    comment_likes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    comment_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    **comment_user_handle = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='Commented_by')**
    comment_post  = models.ForeignKey(UserPost,verbose_name='Post ID')
    comment_liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='Like_List')
```

Comment: No change after doing that. Still get the same error of no such table comment_liked_by